# IV must be 16 bytes long error in AES encryption

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I am using [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) module for AES encryption. And using documentation I have write down the below function but it al;ways gives error `IV must be 16 bytes long` but I am using 16 byte long IV.

```
def aes_encrypt(plaintext):
    """
    """
    key = **my key comes here**
    iv = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16)) # even used without binascii.hexlify)

    aes_mode = AES.MODE_CBC

    obj = AES.new(key, aes_mode, iv)

    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintext)
    return ciphertext
```

Comment: It should work without the hexlify. Try it again and see if you get the same error message.

Comment: Removing `binascii.hexlify` fixes it for me.

Comment: nop , its not working

Comment: If it isn't working, why did you accept an answer that just removed `hexlify`?

Comment: @interjay sorry but after removing `hexlify` , I wrong;y used 32 bytes instead of 16 so it throws me the same error

Comment: Which is why I told you to test it again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES 
import binascii,os

def aes_encrypt(plaintext):
    key = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    aes_mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    obj = AES.new(key, aes_mode, iv)
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintext)
    return ciphertext
```

Works as below:

```
>>> aes_encrypt("TestTestTestTest")
'r_\x18\xaa\xac\x9c\xdb\x18n\xc1\xa4\x98\xa6sm\xd3'
>>>
```

That's the difference:

```
>>> iv =  binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16))
>>> iv
'9eae3db51f96e53f94dff9c699e9e849'
>>> len(iv)
32
>>> iv = os.urandom(16)
>>> iv
'\x16fdw\x9c\xe54]\xc2\x12!\x95\xd7zF\t'
>>> len(iv)
16
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , the len() helps debugging the issue

Comment: IT only accepts input of multiple of 16 ? `Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length`

Comment: @user5594493 Yes, input length of a cipher must be equal with its block cipher. (16 byte for AES 128). For smaller inputs, you must pad the input with a data (maybe with `00`)

Comment: also this AES ciphertext is not json seralizable , so is there any way i can encode this CT and later on decode before decryption so that I can easily pass this CT in my AOI's

Comment: @EbraHim When trying the code, I got `TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code`. Any idea?