# Decoding encrypted files in Python using AES

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes

I have provided encrypted file, key and iv.
Using openssl I can do:

`openssl aes-128-cbc-d -iv 8d8012a7ca3007dcf47e593f37681111 -K 20994d3521a087bcdbb870fc29653512 -in input_file -out output_file`

Now I want to do the same but in Python3.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

ifi = open("input_file", "rb")
ciphertext = ifi.read()
ifi.close()

key = '20994d3521a087bcdbb870fc29653512'
iv = '8d8012a7ca3007dcf47e593f37681111'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
decryptor = AES.new(key, mode, IV=iv)

plain = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)

ofi = open("output_file", "wb")
ofi.write(plain)
ofi.close()
```

I am receiving error: `ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`.
Is it possible to use string as hex key and for hex iv?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IV must be 16 bytes long error in AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834580/iv-must-be-16-bytes-long-error-in-aes-encryption)

Comment: Ty. It solved my problem! :)